# Java casting utility library

Tags: java, generics, casting, unsafe

I'm wondering if there exists a library to perform a bunch of mundane casts (basically a wrapper around a bunch of potentially unsafe casts that, for the most part, isn't an issue in practice).  For example, suppose I have the following in a library (body elided for brevity):

```
public interface LibraryInterface;

public static void doSomething(Collection<LibraryInterface> collection);
```

So `doSomething()` stubbornly only takes something less flexible than what is possible (ie. `Collection<? extends LibraryInterface>`.  Is there a library that provides a function in the same vein as following:

```
public static <T, U extends T> Collection<T> cast(Collection<U> collection);
```

So that if I have a class that implements `LibraryInterface`, and I have a `List<MyLibraryInterfaceImpl>`, I can still use `doSomething()` by casting that list?  (The body of `cast()` is implied to contain the unsafe cast, but at least from the user's standpoint that cast is hidden away, or centralized in one place).

(Also nice, something that does the reverse for something like Comparator)

Answer (score 1):

Such a library would be a non-sense. Because of the type erasure, casting to a parent class does absolutely nothing, except removing a compiler warnings. Moreover what the library would do is either do directly the cast or do a copy of the collection. In other words, it either does exactly what you didn't wanted to do and that motivated you to use this library, or something really inefficient and useless...

Downcasting has much more sense if you want to check the content of your collection before doing an unsafe cast. You can create a function that iterate through the collection to check the type of all element and then return the collection by doing an unsafe cast. You can write this function in ~3 lines ;).

Answer (score 1):

Everything that your `cast(Collection<U> collection)` method does can be achieved by `<T extends LibraryInterface> doSomething(Collection<T> collection)`

What is the extra point of the library?

And also if an API builder has decided to have the type invariant, then that basically means he strictly wants you to honor the contract and provide only `LibraryInterface` or is designed for specific use.
Also in Java generics are `type erasure` You can do this

```
List<? extends Object> p = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

But now `List<? extends Object> p = new ArrayList<? extends Object>();`
The above is illegal. So firstly without typecasting and looping, I do not know of any other way on implementing such a library.

So for what you want to do, had generics been co-variant, that is

`List<Object> p = new ArrayList<String>();`

It would had been possible for whatever you want for what ever purpose. But the above statement is illegal. Hence you cant just omit it.

So the only way of doing the above would be to loop and check and then ultimately type cast.

More info can be found [here](http://jatinpuri.com/2012/11/co-variance-contra-variance/) and [here](http://jatinpuri.com)

Answer (score 1):

Now, what would such a library do?

```
void flexibleDoSomething(Collection<? extends LibraryInterface> collection) {
    doSomething((Collection<LibraryInterface>) collection);
}
```

This method doesn't look like it is worth a library. You don't gain any extra type safety by doing this. Obviously the much better thing would be to fix the other library in the first place. But you can always inline the method.

There are some situations where I've seen such a library in use. Largely to get the casts concentrated in a single class when they are frequent, or because some of them were syntactically messy. E.g. casting `Class<Foo<?>>` to `Class<Foo<Something>>` for complex generics.

Note that when using generics, *every* type should appear on the right side, to make sure it will be properly bound by the compiler.

```
public static <T, U extends T> Collection<T> cast(Collection<U> collection);
```

For this method the compiler will happily assume that `T` is `Object`.

To get stricter generics, you might want to use something like

```
public static <T, U extends T> Collection<T> cast(Collection<U> collection, Class<T> clz);
```

This way, you can actually specify `T`, and (well, not for `Collection`, but for other situations), the utility method could also do some type checking.